# What does the 'man in the hole with two arrows' icon in the top left do?

Tags: dota-2

In Dota 2, in the top bar, the fifth icon from the left is a man in a hole. Clicking it seems to do nothing. What is it supposed to do?

Comment: I don't think it does anything yet, but there are two arrows, one on either side of the man in the hole.  This suggest it is some sort of swap or switch function.

Comment: you should mark right answers. profit for everybody

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The function was implemented yesterday in the test build

It opens a new tab where you can **share control** of your hero,courier,units with desired players.

Also you can prevent other players to use friendly spells on you(eg. if you don't want tiny to toss you).

Answer (score 1):

Most have suggested it will either allow a player to share control of their units with an ally, swap heroes, or disable allied help (VS Swap, Force Staff, etc.). These are the main in-game things that have yet to be added.